# Do % in CSS flow into each other?

Tags: html, css, liquid

I'm trying to turn my fixed site into a fluid site and I have a quick question on how %'s work.

```
    <div class=wrap>
       <div class=box>
         <Div class=text>
       <div class=box>
    <div=class=wrap>

    .wrap{
     width: 100%;
     }

   .box{
   width: 50%
   }

   .text{
   width: 25%
   }
```

Now given this code what happens? the wrap fits the entire screen. The box will fill 50% of the screen, but the text only fills 25% of 50%. It doesn't fill 25% of the entire screen, it only fills the percentage of its containing div. Is that correct?

Comment: That's right. The child element takes the percentage of it's parent element.

Comment: Be careful with the value 100%: what you probably want is **`width: auto`**. Article: [The difference between width:auto and width:100%](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `div` is calculating its dimension from it's `parent`.

Div having class `.Wrap` calculating it's dimension from its parent i.e `body` that's why it takes entire body width.

Have a look in [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: As I think it is the nearest ancestor *block* element, the containing block http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block